# Delete a line from a text file

Tags: c#, file-io

I'm creating a program which goes to website (website list loaded from a text file), does some tasks and after that goes to next website from the text file.

That works, but now I need to delete a line (website) from the file after the program is done with it. How can I do it?

Here's my code for loading txt with websites:

```
DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new
    System.IO.StreamReader(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    split = text.Split(new Char[] {'\n' });
}
```

Comment: The only way to delete a line from a text file is to overwrite the file with everything but that line. Unless you're deleting from the *end* of the file, in which case you could conceivably truncate the file.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than splitting, it's simpler to use [`File.ReadAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) or - from .NET 4 - [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx). The latter reads line by line, so you could use:

```
var linesToKeep = File.ReadLines(file)
                      .Where(line => line != lineYouWantToRemove)
                      .ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(file, linesToKeep);
```

(That would work with `ReadAllLines` too, of course - you'd just end up with more in memory at a time.)

Note that using the `File.*` methods means you don't have to worry about writing `using` statements to close the resources etc - which you don't do in your sample code. (You never close the file handle...)

Comment: Yeah. Besides, splitting on `\n` will leave that pesky line feed.

Comment: @JimMischel: I assume you mean carriage return? But yes :)

Comment: Yes, I meant carriage return. *slaps forehead*

Comment: @JonSkeet : Hey I used your code but the result is that all the data is lost in my file. Hmm what was wrong?

Comment: @Cdeez: I have no idea without any more information. Please post a new question with a short but complete example.